# Calculate nearest point in a orbital path to user (GPS)

Tags: gps, satellite, node-js

TLDR: how do I go about determining the nearest point in an orbital path to a user's location?

Longer version:
This is gonna remain a bit vague, I'm uncertain of the terminology needed to ask/answer this question.

As for background, I'm working on a side project to alert a user when/where a satellite is visible in the night sky.

I've got user GPS coords, and I've been able to snag satellite data from the [TLE API](https://tle.ivanstanojevic.me/#/), and translate that data into GPS coords every 1/4 hour of the satellite's orbital period, giving me a rough idea of its orbital path. A visual example, user location in yellow and points along the orbit in purple: http://geojson.io/#id=gist:DGWIIImelt/65bbaaf46200cb657e9bdb606af59780&map=2/-1.2/-25.3 [image: orbital period]

The part I'm stuck on, **is how do I go about determining the nearest point in that orbital path to the user's location?**

Thus far, I've attempted to use some simple geometry, using triangular rules, grabbing a couple of the orbital path GPS coords along with the user's coords and find the 90* intersection of the orbital path from the user's coord. And I believe the math is working but, it presumes a flat surface (ie Euclidean geometry). However, the Earth ain't flat and the supposed intersection is more inaccurate the further the distances.

I've come across this [site](https://www.movable-type.co.uk) with loads of great examples and descriptions but I'm still lost. I've also come across the concept of great circles, which seems to relate to this problem but I haven't been able to make the connection myself. Any resources to skill up a bit? Even just having some of the terminology laid out.

Comment: `haversine formula` and `ternary method` are two big words that might help

Comment: Is the altitude of the satellite a factor or are you okay with the ground track?

Comment: I'm boiling everything down to GPS coords, at sea level, so ground track. @Spacedman

Comment: @barrycarter I've incorporated the haversine formula and it might be part of the solution here but, from what I understand it requires the two coords to find the distance. I have one coord, the user, and a line/geodesic that I want to find the closest point on.

Comment: Feel free to ping me in chat if you'd like more specific help

Comment: The other point would be the location of the satellite at a given time, no?

Comment: @barrycarter yes. Are you suggesting using Haversine to calculate the distance to the user every say second, store that in a array/dict and find the shortest distance with its associated coords?

Comment: No no no... you can calculate the distance every hour or so (maybe even less) and use the `ternary method` to find the minimum. The ternary method will give you additional times to query, but it doesn't have to be every second. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

Comment: @BarryCarter okay, interesting. So, I could calculate the nearest coords already grabbed every 1/4 hour. Use Haversine to find the closest one. Then increment the lat/lon accordingly to follow the orbital path, hit it with Haversine again, if further away, stay put, if closer, increment again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138068/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-douglas-g-wright-iii).